# Transfer TFS 2012 to another machine

Tags: tfs

Now we plan to move our running Tfs server to another machine in data center.
Running tfs server specifications:
1.Having several tiers: two app tiers and two data tiers

Data center tfs server specifications:
1.Single box topology: the data base and the tfs server in the same virtual machine

We have done the following steps to do backup:

1. Run tfsbackup.exe (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools) to backup the tfs from running tfs

   - Backup all data bases including the report servers (the data bases are selected default by tfsbackup.exe tool)
   - Backup the encryption key for reporting services (followed steps in [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj620932.aspx))

After backup, we do the following to restore the tfs:

1. Log to data center tfs server as tfs service account (the tfs service account should be in local administrator group)
2. Run the TfsRestore.exe (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools) to restore data base backup
3. After restore, open the tfs console to attach the collection from the restored data base

Issue:
When we try to attach the collection, we are blocked at the step to list the available data base: the restored data base can't be listed out.

Could anyone give some suggestion?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, we found out the way to store the tfs is wrong.

Actually we are doing tfs transfer. So we should do the following steps to do tfs transfer and it works:

1. Logon tfs server in data center as tfs service account, and the tfs service account should be  in local administrator group
2. Open tfs console and remove tfs feature : remove the current installed tfs instance
3. Manually delete all tfs related data bases in data base server
4. Be sure the related tfs service is running including www service
5. Run the TfsRestore.exe (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 11.0\Tools) to restore data base backup
6. Run TFS installer and follow the Application-Tier Only wizard to do tfs transfer configuration
7. At the data base step, click list available data base to list the restored data base
8. Restart the tfs server
9. Check the tfs configuration in the tfs console and update some links
  10.

Thanks.